# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

i use springmvc,mybatis,mysql,my mysql username is 'root',password don't set
[this is my error content on the service:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmW9n.png)
[this is mysql contect config in applicationContext.xml:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoEWu.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not mysql issue there is issue in your xml file just remove the line:

```
<property name="password" value="" / >
```

Don't use this line to your code if you are not using password

Comment: it still be wrong that is same after  i remove this line;